# What is the purpose of array[index] = 0;?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
char dev[20] = "dev_name";
char dest[32];
strncpy(dest,dev,sizeof(dev));
dest[sizeof(dev)-1] = 0;
```

What does `dest[sizeof(dev)-1] = 0;` means?

Comment: depends on what `dec_name` is, as opposed to `dev_name`.

Comment: is the `size` really `size` or meant to be `sizeof`?

Comment: @vald Does it make sense to you now ?

Comment: @Quentin how about now? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, assuming `size` is analogous to `sizeof`,

```
 dev_name[size(dec_name)-1] = 0;
```

`dev_name[size(dec_name)-1]` points to the last element of the array, remember `C` arrays use `0` based indexing.

Then, by definition, a *string* in c is exxentially a `char` array **with** null-termination, so if you want to use a char array as *string*, you *must* have the null-termination.

`0` is the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `NUL` or `null`. So, essentially, you're putting a null-terminator to the `char` array.

Comment: Formally it should be: `dev_name[sizeof(dev_name)-1] = '\0';` i.e. put the null character there. At least that shows better you are working with charactes, although the compiler will change the integer `0` to a byte `0`.

Comment: Note also that `strncpy`, when the source is longer than `n`, does *not* put a `\0` there, so you have to do that yourself.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Again, I did not get your comment.

Comment: Sourav, I mean that `0` is the 32 bit (or 64 bit) zero but you want to put only a character-sized zero there, which is denoted by `'\0'`. Again, this is mostly semantics of showing the reader you are working with characters and not ints as the compiler will put the proper type of `0` there.

Comment: Sourav, as to `strncpy`, the whole reason the statement the question is asked about is there, is because ` strncpy` doesn't add the `'\0'` when the source is longer than the target as specified by the 3rd argument of `strncpy`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie 1) regarding readability, I agree. 2) OP wanted to know the _meaning_ of the statement, not the _purpose_, so essentially, the info regarding `strncpy()` though valid, is irrelevant here.

Comment: @PaulOgilive I dont think it should be like '\0', because to make an index NUL, my code is working out properly.

Comment: @Chauhan a `0` and `'\0'` means the same in this context. None is wrong, both are correct and can be used interchangeably.  You can try if you want. :-)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `'\0'` has type `int` in C, so `'\0'` and `0` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean all the element of that array are assigned zero?

No it does not mean this.

Assuming you meant `strncpy(dest,dev_name,sizeof(dev_name)); /* Extra bracket */` and `dev_name` and `sizeof` in you last line; You are assigning NUL character to the last to mark the end of name array.

When you write a string literal like "foo", it is automatically NUL terminated by the compiler. When you take your own arrays, you sometimes need to mark the end of string manually.

From `man strncpy`

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src
>   are copied.  Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes
>   of src, the string placed in dest **will not be null-terminated**.

Explicitly the null-termination is added to handle the warning case in your code snippet.

`dev_name[0]`, `dev_name[1]`, `dev_name[2]` etc are first, second, third ... characters of your string. Assuming device name has less than 31 characters, it is automatically NUL terminated after `strncpy` and you don't need to do anything.

If the name has exactly `31` character, last character character (32<sup>nd</sup>) is already `'\0'` (ascii code 0) and writing 0 again over it does not make any difference.

If the name has more than `31` character (corner case), last character character is not NUL and `dev_name[sizeof(dev_name)-1] = 0;` will make the name NUL terminated.